# NHibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a getter for property in class

Tags: c#, hibernate, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace web_nt.Models
{
    public class Transport
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string lic_plate { get; set; }
        public virtual string model { get; set; }
        public virtual string made_date { get; set; }
        public virtual string status { get; set; }
        public virtual string region { get; set; }
        public virtual string rida { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Mapping:

```
  <class name="Transport" table="transport" dynamic-update="false" lazy="false">
    <cache usage="read-write"/>
    <id name="Id" column="Id" type="int">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="lic_plate" />
    <property name="model" />
    <property name="made_date" />
    <property name="status" />
    <property name="region" />
    <property name="rida" />
  </class
```

I get error: NHibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a getter for property 'rida' in class 'web_nt.Models.Transport'

Could not find a getter for property 'rida' in class 'web_nt.Models.Transport'

And it seems that Nhibernate does not find 'rida', but if I delete this property everything works. And its same with any other propertys I add (since there are few more that exists)
How could I fix  this?

Comment: where id Rida property in your class??

Answer (score 1):

Well, the `<property name="rida" />` assumes that there is a property named `rida` in the class you're mapping. Either add the property to the `Transport` class, or remove the `<property />` tag from the HBM file.

Comment: Sorry for mistakes, ridas was declered there(just was expermenting with odometer and other propertys and forgot to change it). But the error seems the same.

Comment: It is same. Seems like nhibernate can't find rida.

Comment: Clean up the solution and recompile. Ensure that everything compiles clearly.

Comment: I'v tried that. I see 'rida' in my class, but I still get error that it does not exists.

Comment: One more thing to add: I tried to delete Transport.cs class and everything works, program finds that class and uses it (It's like that my class is in other place and what I am editing is something else)

Comment: are you sure all the projects in your solution are being built? in VS from build menu -> configuration manager -> make sure all projects are checked for build.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, in the end it was an old dll in the root of my application. I load the mappings from a specific subfolder, not from app root, but this dead dll lost there was been loaded by framework